# Android Exception FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
F/flutter (13556): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(60)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
F/libc    (13556): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13556 (yapp.mysurvey)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/MHA-L29/HWMHA:8.0.0/HUAWEIMHA-L29/366(C636):user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 13556, tid: 13556, name: yapp.mysurvey>>> com.myapp.mysurvey <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(60)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
```

I got this error the app is build.

I got included this in my pubspec.ymal file

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.5
  firebase_database: ^0.4.6
  firebase_storage: ^0.3.0
  f_grecaptcha: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: See the https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10771

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem in android

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, in app/build.gradle add the following code but the APK size will increase i.e from 31MB to 35MB.

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
       
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
```

Comment: How about if i really want to reduce APK/AAB size?

Answer (score 0):

**@jibril90** Thanks! It it helps me.

This code in `app/build.gradle` fixed an issue, but increased app size (ok in my case):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nuts's answer
[Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60994010/10417992)

You can add the next line inside app/build.gradle

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms: play-services-base: 17.0.0") {force = true}
```

It worked properly for me

Answer (score 0):

the easiest  way is to run `flutter clean` in your terminal that always fixes many errors