# Flutter app crashing on android 10 & R with No static method isAtLeastR

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services

I've seen a few issues similar on Stack overflow, but not one that quite relates to the same libraries.

I'm trying to use 2 plugins in flutter
flutter_geofence and geolocator

They've both been working fine, but since yesterday as soon as of the location play services are called I'm getting the app quit with a stack trace similar to below:

```
E/flutter (11478): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class Landroidx/core/os/BuildCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.BuildCompat' appears in /data/app/com.mypossibleself.app-FTu9V5QDAKR_ngQmuPzg7Q==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.google.android.gms.common.util.PlatformVersion.isAtLeastR(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:21)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:128)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:41)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:56)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Unknown Source:2)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.baseflow.geolocator.tasks.LocationUpdatesUsingLocationServicesTask.<init>(LocationUpdatesUsingLocationServicesTask.java:29)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.baseflow.geolocator.tasks.TaskFactory.createStreamLocationUpdatesTask(TaskFactory.java:120)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin.onListen(GeolocatorPlugin.java:110)
E/flutter (11478):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onListen(EventChannel.java:193)
E/flutter (11478):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onMessage(EventChannel.java:172)
E/flutter (11478):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
E/flutter (11478):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
E/flutter (11478):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (11478):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (11478):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/flutter (11478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/flutter (11478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/flutter (11478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

So it's complaining about a missing method isAtLeastR

Other references I've seen to this mention specific versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-base causing this, but that it's fixed in com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1

Neither of these library implement that package in their build.gradle files so I'm at a loss as to what needs doing to fix this issue.

Comment: So your  app/build.gradle has ` com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1` in it? Did you do flutter clean before running?

Comment: Yep, I've spent over 24 hours on this. I've done a clean. We don't directly access com.google.android.gms:play-services-base in our app/build.gradle at all. Do you think it'd help if we did? It'll be coming from a library I'd guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the app/build.gradle add  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1` this should make libraries use specific version of play-services.

If it doesn't help, might need to

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.needed_dependency'
    }
}
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#conflict-resolution

Edit as per Andrews suggestion:

17.2.1 doesn't work, but 17.0.0 does.

```
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"){ force = true }
```

Comment: I've ended up with something slightly different, but you pointed me in the right direction. 17.2.1 doesn't work for me but 17.0.0 does. I've also ended up going for this definition. implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"){
    force = true
}

Comment: I will update the answer with your comment. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Andrew where exactly did you add this line?

Comment: For reference....Similar issue using Firebase plugins. 17.2.1 didn't work but 17.1 did with force. However given this is a few months later 17.3.0 is available and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0' 
        }           
}
```

This is what solved it for me.